# How to get file content by Retrofit2, if URL starts to download file

Tags: android, retrofit2

The URL https://itunes.apple.com/search?term=lennon
starts to download file.
HTTP request using HttpURLConnection and InputStream returns the json string.
It is  what I need.

But how to get string response using Retrofit2?
I tryed the following code:

```
public interface ItunesApi {
   @GET("/search")
   Call<SongsGson> getData(@Query("term=") String search);
}
```

I send the request here:

```
    Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl("https://itunes.apple.com/")
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build();
    ItunesApi itunesApi = retrofit.create(ItunesApi.class);

    itunesApi.getData(searchString).enqueue(new Callback<SongsGson>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<SongsGson> call, Response<SongsGson>  response) {
            int resultCount = response.body().getResultCount();
        }
        ...
    }
```

resultCount is always equal 0.
response.isSuccessful()=true response.message()=OK
The class is below:

```
public class SongsGson {
   @SerializedName("resultCount")
   @Expose
   private int resultCount;

   public SongsGson(){}

   public void setResultCount(int resultCount){
     this.resultCount = resultCount;
   }

   public int getResultCount() {
     return resultCount;
   }
 }
```

Any ideas, please!

Comment: check response.isSuccessful() and response.message() for some more info

Comment: response.isSuccessful()=true response.message()=OK

Comment: Long shot, but I'd try removing the ``=`` from ``@Query("term=")``. My guess is that retrofit encodes the ``=`` and you get the wrong query parameter name in the url.